# Execute multiple cmd commands using Python for MySQL Dump import

Tags: python, mysql, operating-system

I'm trying to import a MySQL Dump file onto my Local Server using Python but have some errors.

If I execute the two following commands separately in cmd prompt window it works fine:

```
--> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"
--> mysql -u root -p database < "C:\Users\Tom\data.sql"
```

However, I want to automate this and have thus tried the following in Python:

```
import os
p = 'mysql -u root -p database < "C:\Users\Tom\data.sql"'
os.system('cmd /c "CD "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\\bin &&""' + p)
```

Error shown:

```
Syntax Error: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec cant decode bytes in position 44-45: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is that you also have to escacpe the \ from the path

\u for example stands for that after that comes a unicode sequence, so with escaping the backslyash you python doesn't do that anymore

```
import os
p = "mysql -u root -p database < \"C:\\Users\\Tom\\data.sql\""
os.system('CD "c:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\bin\n"' + p)
```

it runs(but it shows that the folder doesn't exist=
[image: python output]

Comment: This doesn't seem to seem fixed it!  The same error simply appears?

Comment: it works on my system, the rerro message doesn't appear while debigging and the system says it does have the folder.

Comment: i also added a scereenshot, so  that you can see no problems and no error message

Comment: Ok the error is different now, It says : "'""mysql' is not recognsied as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"